# nodejs app (with websockets) works on 12.04 but not on 14.04

Tags: node.js, proxy, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-14.04

We have a nodejs "custom" app that acts as a LB/proxy for http requests. I detected that, on Ubuntu 14.04, the LB acts strangely. 1 out of 10 websocket requests are correctly responded to the websocket client (on Ubuntu 14.04), but if I run the proxy/LB on Ubuntu 12.04 all works fine.

The most oddly/random thing I found is if I 'strace' the proxy/LB process on Ubuntu 14.04, all works fine! Stop the strace, and fails, start the strace, all is good. I'm 
driving crazy!

Both were fresh installs on EC2, with the latest updates installed

Anyone have a clue of what is happening?

Comment: Can you tell us which components and version you're using? Also, did you check logs and/or find anything abnormal?

Comment: I checked system logs and app logs, nothing abnormal. I tried running the app as root, changing node version (we use 0.8.x), updating the ws module, nothing fixed it. The nodejs proxy/LB app uses module http-proxy 0.8.7, async 0.2.6, commander 1.1.1, crypto-reader 0.0.1, ws 0.5.0 and request 2.48.0